# What sets are there with order type $\omega^2$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I’ve recently been thinking about order types of sets, and I can’t come up with a set of natural numbers order type $\omega^2$ or $\omega\cdot\omega$.
If someone could help me by giving an example it would be appreciated.
-Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect to find a set of natural numbers with that order type?

Comment: If $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers, you can't find any set which would be naturally of type $\omega^2$? You are really not seeing the forest for the trees.

Comment: Depends on the kind of forest... Some don’t have trees... and I still get lost in them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like:

$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0, & 1, & 3, & 6, & 10, & \dots\\
2, & 4, & 7, & 11, & 16, & \dots\\
5, & 8, & 12, & 17, & 23, & \dots\\
9, & 13, & 18, & 24, & 31, & \dots\\
14, & 19, & 25, & 32, & 49, & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
\\
\\
\end{array}$

So the set of natural numbers ordered by: $0,1,3,6,10,\dots,2,4,7,11,16,\dots$

Comment: This works, thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome.